# Selecting rows where condition given by column x is true for values in column y

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
Column_X    Column_Y    A-Indicator
   Val1        A           True
   Val1        B           True
   Val2        B           False
   Val2        B           False
```

I want to create the "A-Indicator" column. This column is True for all rows with Column_X = 'Val1' if a single Val1-row has Column_Y = A. Since no rows with Column_X = 'Val2' has Column_Y = 'A', the A-indicator is false for all these rows. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is important, don use `groupby`:

```
df['A-Indicator'] = df['Column_X'].isin(df.loc[df['Column_Y'].eq('A'), 'Column_X'].unique())
print (df)
  Column_X Column_Y  A-Indicator
0     Val1        A         True
1     Val1        B         True
2     Val2        B        False
3     Val2        B        False
```

**Explanation**:

First compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html) `(==)`:

```
print (df['Column_Y'].eq('A'))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: Column_Y, dtype: bool
```

Find all values of column `Column_X`:

```
print (df.loc[df['Column_Y'].eq('A'), 'Column_X'])
0    Val1
Name: Column_X, dtype: object
```

Get unique values for better performance:

```
print (df.loc[df['Column_Y'].eq('A'), 'Column_X'].unique())
['Val1']
```

And last compare by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df['Column_X'].isin(df.loc[df['Column_Y'].eq('A'), 'Column_X'].unique()))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: Column_X, dtype: bool
```

**Performance**: It depends of number of rows and number of matched values:

```
np.random.seed(123)

N = 1000000
L = list('ABCDEFGHIJK')
df = pd.DataFrame({
                      'Column_X':np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                      'Column_Y': np.random.choice(L, N),
                  })
print (df)

In [193]: %timeit df['A-Indicator'] = df['Column_X'].isin(df.loc[df['Column_Y'].eq('A'), 'Column_X'].unique())
92.1 ms ± 396 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [194]: %timeit df['A-Indicator']=df.groupby('Column_X')['Column_Y'].transform(lambda x: x.isin(['A']).any())
724 ms ± 3.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [195]: %timeit df['A-Indicator']=df.groupby('Column_X')['Column_Y'].transform(lambda x: 'A' in x.unique())
770 ms ± 48.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my issue! And thanks for the explanation.